# visual studio plugin for macro alignment

Tags: macros, format, alignment

how to easily format C++ macro defination?
my code is below:

```
#define SADSKKHDJJKSDF 1
#define FD 2
#define KJDSKJFD 3
```

what i want like this:

```
#define SADSKKHDJJKSDF 1
#define FD             2
#define KJDSKJFD       3
```

for now, i'm using vs2008 plubin "AStyle", it will help me a lot about my code excep macro.

yeah, who can help me, thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use Code Alignment plugin http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7179e851-a263-44b7-a177-1d31e33c84fd/

Here are the setup instructions http://www.codealignment.com/ForVisualStudio.html

Then you can select your text. Use "AlignByString" ans check "Align from caret position"